# Specify concat_dim for xarray open_mfdataset

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm using `xarray.open_mfdataset()` to open and combine 8 netcdf files (output from model simulations with different settings) without loading them into memory. This works great if I specify `concat_dim='run_number'`, which adds `run_number` as a dimension without coordinates and just fills it with values from 0 to 7.

The problem is that now, I don't know which run_number belongs to which simulation. The original netcdf's all have attributes that help me to distinguish them, e.g. `identifyer=1`, `identifyer=2`, etc., but this is not recognized by xarray, even if I specify `concat_dim='identifyer'` (perhaps because there are many attributes?).

Is there any way in which I can tell xarray that it has to use this attribute as `concat_dim`? Or alternatively, in which order does xarray read the input files, so that I can infer which value of the new dimension corresponds to which simulation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xarray will use the values of existing scalar coordinates to label result coordinates, but it doesn't look at attributes. Only looking at metadata found in coordinates is a [general theme](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/faq.html#what-is-your-approach-to-metadata) in xarray: we leave `attrs` to user code only. So this should work you assign scalar `'identifyer'` coordinates to each dataset, e.g., using the `preprocess` argument to `open_mfdataset`:

```
def add_id(ds):
    ds.coords['identifyer'] = ds.attrs['identifyer']
    return ds

xarray.open_mfdataset(path, preprocess=add_id)
```

Alternatively, you can either pass an explicit list of filenames to `open_mfdataset` or rely on the fact that `open_mfdataset` sorts the glob of filenames before combining them: the datasets will always be combined in lexicographic order of their names.

Comment: One minor remark: I had to add `return ds` to the function for it to work.